# Sending file from html form with Laravel-Mailgun API

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, mailgun

I'm trying to send a file selected by the user via the HTML form and send it as an email attachment with Mailgun. I do not want to store this file anywhere in my server. I need to be able to upload all kinds of files (png, pdf, word...).

This what I've been trying so far.

Frontend looks like this :

HTML

```
<label>
       Click to attach file...
       <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload" name="fileToUpload">
</label>
```

Script (VueJS)

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', this.welcomeMail.attachment);


axios
.post('/admin/customersV2/sendWelcomeMail',formData,
{
    headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Backend (php-Laravel) looks like this :

```
$mgClient->messages()->send($domain,
    array('from'    => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
        'to'      => $request->emailAddress,
        'cc' => env('MAIL_CC'),
        'subject' => 'Greetings',
        'template'    => 'welcome-template',
        'attachment' => [
            [
                'filePath' => $request->file->path(),
                'fileName' => 'Attachment'
            ]
        ],
        'h:X-Mailgun-Variables'    => $mailgunVariables)
```

But in my email the attachment is empty (see below screenshot):

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try `$request->file('file')` instead of `$request->file->path()`?

Comment: Still not working.. I have the same temporarily file attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've finally done it. Problem was coming from the backend, I had to add file_get_contents to get all the file data contained into one string.

```
    $mgClient->messages()->send($domain,
        array('from'    => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
            'to'      => $request->emailAddress,
            'cc' => env('MAIL_CC'),
            'subject' => 'Greetings from Eatology',
            'template'    => 'welcome-template',
            'attachment' => [
                [
                    'fileContent' => file_get_contents($request->file('file')),
                    'filename' => 'attachment.' . $request->file('file')->extension()
                ]
            ],
            'h:X-Mailgun-Variables'    => $mailgunVariables)
    );
```